QTextEdit can't insertPlainText after insertHtml
QTextEdit can't insertPlainText after insertHtml.
QTextEdit inserts html and then inserts plain text. Plain text is still displayed in html format.
Is this a bug? Or am I using the wrong method.

I want to add html first and then plain text, and they will display properly, what do I do.

The documentation is quite clear.
QTextEdit::insertPlainText() says that:

It is equivalent to
edit->textCursor().insertText()

Which, in turn, clearly says that:

Inserts text at the current position, using the current character format.

So, follow the simple procedure:

insert the HTML;
get the textCursor();
use setCharFormat() with an empty QTextCharFormat() instance;
set the text cursor again to the text edit with setTextCursor() so that the format is actually applied for new insertions;
call insertPlainText();

I strongly recommend you to read the documentation about to the Qt rich text processing and the related topics, such as its structure and classes (starting from QTextDocument and QTextCursor).

Thank you very much for your answer. I understand completely now.
I did not read the official document carefully before, and I will take your advice to read it carefully.
